# Proof of a matrix

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Suppose $ M= \begin{pmatrix} 5 & -1 \\ 4 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $. Prove that $\forall n\in \mathbb N $ the following equation holds :

$M^n = 3^{n-1} \begin{pmatrix} 2n+3 & -n\\ 4n & 3- 2n \end{pmatrix}$

I've already proven this as follows:

$\underline{n=0:}$  is trivial just as ${n=1}$ which is given.

$\underline{I.H.:}$ (n=k) Suppose the above statement is true $\forall n \in \mathbb N. $

$\underline{n=k+1:}$

$\begin{align}M^{k+1}& =^{I.H.} 3^{k-1}\begin{pmatrix}2k+3 & -k\\ 4k&3-2k \end{pmatrix} \cdot 3 \begin{pmatrix}5 & -1 \\ 4 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\\
&=  3^{k-1} \begin{pmatrix} 6k+15 & -3k-3\\ 12k+12 & -6k+3  \end{pmatrix}\\
& = 3^k \begin{pmatrix} 2k+5 & -k-1\\ 4k+4 & -2k+1  \end{pmatrix}\\ 
& = 3^n \begin{pmatrix} 2n+3 & -n\\ 4n & -2n+3  \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}
$

> My question now is how do I determine a matrix $P^2= M$?

What I've tried is the following:

$\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{21} & a_{22}\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{21} & a_{22}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 5 & -1\\ 4 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$

Now I got stuck on this system of equations. I tried using other variables such as x, y, z and u to make it clearer for me but nevertheless I still didn't solve this problem. Would someone help me with this problem please? And maybe check my proof above?

Comment: It might be easier to build up to $M^{n+1}$ from $M^n$ instead of starting with $M^{n+1}$.  Also, you say let $n=k+1$, but then use $n+1$ in the computation.

Comment: yeah that was my mistake. I used n+1 on my paper.

Comment: Your inductive hypothesis is wrong.  You don't assume that the statement is true for all $n$, that's what you want to prove.  Instead, you want to prove that "*IF* the statement is true when $n=k$, then the statement is true when $n=k+1$."  Once you have proved that, the *result* is that the statement is true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Oke but those are just minor details which are important but I just wanted to know if my elaboration in the n+1 case is correct?

Comment: I've edit your remarks in my question.

Comment: The first step of the inductive hypothesis is missing a matrix, so you have a number equal to a matrix.  You can factor $n+1$ in the final matrix and you'll have a matrix of the correct form.

Comment: Why do you need $P^2=M$?

Comment: It is a question in my exercise.

Comment: @MichaelBurr  And I will try to do that.

Comment: The problem that I see is that the inductive step is never related to $M^{k+1}$.  What is done is that you've shown how to make the necessary simplification, but not quite how to get there (how is what you write related to $M$)?

Comment: I don't know what you exactly mean? I try to believe that they are related?

Comment: The first line of your inductive step is $$3^{(k+1)-1}=^{I.H.} 3^{k-1}\begin{pmatrix}2k+3 & -k\\ 4k&3-2k \end{pmatrix} \cdot 3 \begin{pmatrix}5 & -1 \\ 4 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$  The LHS doesn't have a matrix, but even if it had a matrix, there's no $M$ here.  You're missing how this, explicitly relates to $M^{k+1}$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I was too fast with my proof. I didn't even remark that.

Comment: I'll edit it asap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is somewhat confused. First of all the induction hypothesis in **not** that the statement is true for all $n$, nothing good can come from such an assumption. Instead you assume that it's true for a specific $n$ and show that it's true for the next integer $n+1$.

Then the next question about finding $P$ such that $P^2=M$ the identity that you've shown is a clue here. Insert $n=1/2$ into the formula. Of course your proof has not shown it to work for non-integers, but let's give it a try:

$$\left(3^{1/2-1}\begin{pmatrix}
2 (1/2) + 3 & -(1/2) \\
4(1/2) & 3 -2(1/2) \\
\end{pmatrix}\right)^2 
\\= {1\over3}\begin{pmatrix}
4 & -1 \\
2 & 2
\end{pmatrix}^2\\
= \begin{pmatrix}
5 & -1 \\
4 & 1\end{pmatrix} = M$$

Well it worked out - and that's all you need for an answer (no reason to justify a "lucky" guess).

Comment: Oh oké. I just need to broaden the n to the rational numbers and just used the inverse of the power of P. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AnonymousI Nota bene that the proof for the formula is **not** valid for arbitrary rational number - it's just took a guess at using the formula and we turned out lucky.  One can prove that the formula is indeed valid for arbitrary rational numbers (by using Jordan normal form), but that's not needed for this question (as I pointed out that if we just happen to pick a matrix whose square happens to be $M$ we're done).

Answer (score 1):

For the question about $P^2=M$, one way to solve it would be to use the Jordan form:

$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}1&.5\\2&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\0&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&.5\\2&-1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then, it is enough to find a matrix whose square is $\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\0&3\end{bmatrix}$, this can be done by hand to find 
$$\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{3}&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\\0&\sqrt{3}\end{bmatrix}$$

Then
$$
P=\begin{bmatrix}1&.5\\2&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{3}&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\\0&\sqrt{3}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&.5\\2&-1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I see (beyond the typos) is that the inductive step is never related to $M^{k+1}$.  What is done is that you've shown how to make the necessary simplification, but not quite how to get there (how is what you write related to $M$)?

For the inductive hypothesis:

Assume that the statement is true when $n=k$. In other words:
$$
M^k=3^{k-1}\begin{bmatrix}2k+3&-k\\4k&3-2k\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Multiplying both sides by $M$ gives
\begin{align}
M^{k+1}&=3^{k-1}\begin{bmatrix}2k+3&-k\\4k&3-2k\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}5&-1\\4&1\end{bmatrix}\\
&=3^{k-1}\begin{bmatrix}6k+15&-3k-3\\12k+12&3-6k\end{bmatrix}\\
&=3^k\begin{bmatrix}2k+5&-k-1\\4k+4&1-2k\end{bmatrix}\\
&=3^{(k+1)-1}\begin{bmatrix}2(k+1)+3&-(k+1)\\4(k+1)&3-2(k+1)\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
which is of the desired form.  The work above starts somewhere in the middle of the final computation, but doesn't relate the computation to $M^{k+1}$.

Comment: Oh, oké. I've done that on my paper. But I wanted to shorten the proof here because it took a lot of time. And I was really focused on the $P^2 = M$ question.

Comment: My apologies for the unclear proof.

Comment: If you want useful feedback on your proof, then you really should include all of the steps that you've done.  In this case, shortening it damaged the proof.

Comment: Yeah I see. I'll take that into account in the future.

Comment: Do you have a hint on how to prove my intended question?

Comment: It would be better to not mix two questions, one about the induction and one about the $P^2=M$.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was fine because it was a follow-up question on the proof.

Comment: I'll write the entire follow-up question now. "Are you able to determine a matrix $P$ such $P^2 = M$ , now that you know this (referring to the claim above for $M^n$ ),

Comment: The question is already answered above, so I guess, no need at this point.

Comment: Yep, I really appreciate your efforts for clarifyin my way of proving.